# Installing and Configuring xvfb

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, xvfb

I'm trying to find a Ubuntu operating system, version of xorg, and version of xvfb that are compatible. Can anyone help me with directions to install xvfb without getting a hang on
Initializing build-in extension GLX

So far I've tried the following

```
Ubuntu 13 Server(No graphics card)
sudo apt-get install xorg 
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

I run the command `xvfb :10` and it hangs on

```
Initializing build-in extension GLX
```

Are there specific versions I could download that will work or a operating system that would be compatible?

Comment: on 14.04 ubuntu server i get this problem too.

Answer (score 19):

Install Xvfb or Xephyr or Xvnc. Also install pyvirtualdisplay python module. This is for Ubuntu 14.04 and tested on 16.04 as well.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install xvfb xserver-xephyr vnc4server
sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
# optional
sudo apt-get install python-pil scrot
sudo pip install pyscreenshot
```

Now you can start Xvfb from your python script. It will start Xvfb when your script will be executed. Add the following lines to your code.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()
```

Here is the example code.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

Answer (score 9):

**Here is what I do:**

apt install xvfb

Xvfb&

xvfb-run someprogram

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/using_Xvfb_on_virtual_remote_ssh_server_to_have_X_graphical_programs_work-2287-articles

Comment: Thanks. Much easier to use `xvfb-run <myprogram>` then configuring xvfb.

Answer (score 6):

The output means xvfb **works fine**. It should run as a background process (or service).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. To clarify... the fact it hangs is ok? Should I control-C out of the process when it hangs?

Comment: @Ribena - if you wish to run xvfb in order to have other programs use it; than xvfb process **must** be execute as a background process (i.e. `xvfb [args] &`). If you'll execute it, and _control-C out of the process_, it will be terminated and other programs won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

in my log files i see everything is okay up to Initializing built-in extension GLX
 but then it is followed by

```
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86AudioMicMute
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

may be the key issue is with xkbcomp?

Answer (score -1):

You can try pyvirtualdisplay [LINK HERE](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.in/2011/06/python-headless-selenium-webdriver.html). Further, This may be helpful: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498551/selenium-pyvirtualdisplay-hangs-on-starting)