# Selenium Pyvirtualdisplay Hangs on starting

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, headless, headless-browser, pyvirtualdisplay

I have a selenium test which I am trying to run Headlessly on my ubuntu server. It uses pyvirtualdisplay and xephyr. Though the script is running fine in my local system, it hangs when I run it in the server. I have tried to clear memory and restarting the server. But no luck. The script looks something like this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1366, 768)
driver.get ("http://www.google.com/")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 14):

Okay, finally I got through it.

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic

sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer

sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf

sudo dpkg-reconfigure x-ttcidfont-conf
```

chose `freetype`, after that,
when I did `xvfb-run firefox`
then I started getting errors like this :

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".

(firefox:4691): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

(firefox:4691): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Error spawning command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=c4970e12ff5496da09501f87000001fe --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory)

(firefox:4691): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

To resolve, do this :

`apt-get install dbus-x11`